# How to add About dialog to project

Tags: qt, qt5, qdialog, about-box

I have just completed my first Qt 5 project and I want to add an About dialog. Is there a default, and how do you use it? If not, what's the best way to add one and edit it and display its content using the Help menu action? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way to add a dialog to your project depends a little bit on what development environment you are using. You can always use QtDesigner (part of Qt) to design your About dialog and then add it to your project. To display it, just call the `exec()` function of the `QDialog` class in a slot connected to the `triggered()` signal of your About QAction object.